# Disqus API create post, parameter issue: thread id gets posted instead of message

Tags: http, post, disqus

I am trying to create a post via Disqus API.

I was trying this via Python `requests`, but I got confused so I went to the API console and observed that the parameters get mixed up.

Here's how I have posted the parameters on the console page:

`POST` method, the endpoint is set to `Posts > create`

[image]

The other params I send are `api_secret` and `access_token`.

The comment appears in the thread but strangely, the `message` field and the `thread` get mixed up. The thread id appears in the comment:

[image]

What is wrong here? Does the order in which the params are attached matter?

EDIT: Tried again without the quote signs in the message value field, thread id appears in the comment, as above.

Comment: It's a bug with the API console, but usually only after you've made a request. If you refresh the page, it should be fixed again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have spotted it. It looks like a bug.

Chromium Dev tools:

[image]

The `thread` id gets copied and sent as `message`, too.